# How to center a button and that its width is a percentage of the container?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, center

I am making an application in Android Studio and I need a button to be in the center of the phone's screen.

I have seen many examples of how to center a button, but in addition to that, once it is in the center, the width of the button must be 60% of the width of the screen.

Any idea, suggestion or example is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MishaAkopov's answer is good but I will offer a separate solution using Linear Layout.

By setting the weightsum of the layout to 10 and the weight of the button to 6 the button will be 60% of the layouts width.  In addition you need to set the gravity of the `LinearLayout` to center or center_horizontal to ensure the button is centered.

```
<LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:weightSum="10">

     <Button
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:layout_weight="6"
         android:text="My Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ahh, good point :) I completely moved to ConstraintLayout and forgot about old school layouts :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try `ConstraintLayout`. What it does is adds two Guidlines from left (20%) and right (80%) and sets your button's left and right constraints to those guidlines :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]